# Animiation self-build bar

Tags: html, css

i am displaying a bar (div) which shows your level of healthy eating and sports. It has values from 0 - 100%. On page reload a javascript let the div grow from 0% to the the reached level e.g. 70%. But it looks really haltingly its not fluently growing in a consistent way. Do you have any hints to solve that? `obj.aktivitaetIndex3Tage` carries the value and `balkenAktivitaet` is the div which shows the value by its length. It all works fine it just looks so poor because its not fluently growing.

Thanks a lot.

```html
<div style="padding: 0px 0px 15px 10px;color:white;font-size:16px;font-weight:400">
    AKTIVITÄT
</div>
<div style="margin: 0px auto 15px auto;display:flex;flex-wrap:nowrap;">
    <div style="margin:0px;width:80%;height:26px;background-color: #326a68;display:flex;flex-wrap:nowrap;border:1px solid #001c1a;box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #002321;border-radius:5px;">
        <div id="balkenAktivitaet" style="margin:0px;background-color: #F9BC60;height:26px;width:0%;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;box-shadow:1px 0px #001c1a;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="aktivitaetsIndex3Tage" class="indexProzentzahl" style="margin:0% 0% 0% 2%;color:#F9BC60;font-size:26px;font-weight:400;"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var i = 0;
var inv = setInterval(function aktivitaet() {
    if (i < obj.aktivitaetIndex3Tage && i <= 100) {
        document.getElementById("balkenAktivitaet").style.width = parseInt(i = i + 2) + "%";
    }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the width of your div to the desired percentage at once, while adding transition to its css - for expample:

CSS:

```
#balkenAktivitaet {
   transition: width 2s ease;
   width: 0%;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("balkenAktivitaet").style.width = obj.aktivitaetIndex3Tage + '%';
```

Example Codepen: https://codepen.io/furiosys/pen/PobvpKa